Oracle instance automatically starting after SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE command
DB: 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0
OS: RHEL server 5.8
I'm trying to shutdown an oracle instance, but every time I try the following ORA-03113 error appears and the instance restarts itself:

sys@db_name> shutdown immediate
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel

I don't think it's because of the internet. I checked the alert_SID.log and trace file, but didn't find any error log.
This is the the /etc/oratab:
'$ORACLE_SID:/home/oracle/product/11.2.0/db:N'

And lsnrctl has no problem, tnsping local is working.
How to shutdown the instance without starting itself. how to troubleshoot?
The alert_SID.log:

Shutting down instance (immediate)
Stopping background process SMCO
Shutting down instance: further logons disabled
Stopping background process QMNC
Mon Sep 30 15:11:13 2024
Stopping background process CJQ0
Stopping background process MMNL
Stopping background process MMON
License high water mark = 7
All dispatchers and shared servers shutdown
ALTER DATABASE CLOSE NORMAL
Mon Sep 30 15:11:18 2024
SMON: disabling tx recovery
SMON: disabling cache recovery
Mon Sep 30 15:11:18 2024
Shutting down archive processes
Archiving is disabled
Mon Sep 30 15:11:18 2024
ARCH shutting down
Mon Sep 30 15:11:18 2024
ARCH shutting down
ARC3: Archival stopped
ARC2: Archival stopped
Mon Sep 30 15:11:18 2024
Mon Sep 30 15:11:18 2024
ARCH shutting downARCH shutting down

ARC1: Archival stoppedARC0: Archival stopped

Thread 1 closed at log sequence 70830
Successful close of redo thread 1
Completed: ALTER DATABASE CLOSE NORMAL
ALTER DATABASE DISMOUNT
Shutting down archive processes
Archiving is disabled
Completed: ALTER DATABASE DISMOUNT
ARCH: Archival disabled due to shutdown: 1089
Shutting down archive processes
Archiving is disabled
ARCH: Archival disabled due to shutdown: 1089
Shutting down archive processes
Archiving is disabled
Mon Sep 30 15:11:20 2024
Stopping background process VKTM
Mon Sep 30 15:11:21 2024
License high water mark = 7
USER (ospid: 28768): terminating the instance
Instance terminated by USER, pid = 28768
Mon Sep 30 15:11:23 2024
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
****************** Large Pages Information *****************

Total Shared Global Region in Large Pages = 0 KB (0%)

Large Pages used by this instance: 0 (0 KB)
Large Pages unused system wide = 0 (0 KB) (alloc incr 64 MB)
Large Pages configured system wide = 0 (0 KB)
Large Page size = 2048 KB


Welcome to the DBA.SE community. What does the internet have to do with your issues? Or do you mean you are not issuing the SHUTDOWN command remotely? Are you running the command on the server when you write I'm doing it locally? What version of Oracle are you using? What OS is the Oracle instance running on (please add version tag)? Please click on [edit] and add this information to your question. Thanks.

please post the result of ps -ef | grep smon

You may have the Oracle Restart feature enabled, see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/restart.htm for some background.
If so, using SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE means that the database instance is perceived as having failed, and it is automatically restarted. You would need to use the srvctl command while logged in as the oracle user in Linux. There are different forms of syntax to do the same thing; the manual page suggests using something like srvctl stop database -d myorcl -o immediate. This might shut down the listener as well, depending on how the services have been defined.

when I try the srvctl it's giving me error:
****Unable to retrieve Oracle Clusterware home.
Start Oracle Clusterware stack and try again.
so the server is not managed by srvctl and even crs is not available
crsctl check crs
-bash: crsctl: command not found
